# Force a prompt for credential when accessing a shared folder - Windows 10

Tags: networking, shared-folders

How do I set shared folder with credential?

I have set a homegroup between `PC-1`(e.g `xxx.xxx.xx.10`) and `PC-2` (e.g `xxx.xxx.xx.20`).In `PC-1` I'm sharing with folder name `test`.

I'm accessing from `PC-2` using path "`\\xxx.xxx.xx.10\test`" it works but it didn't ask any credential.

Is it possible to set asking credential before direct accessing the folder?

ps: Without using third party application

Comment: The username on both machines may be the same in your work group and perhaps it's authenticating that way due to matching username and passwords from both the machines you are using to access and defined the share. You could create another local account on the machine the shared folder is setup and set the share and NTFS permissions so only it has access. This way as long as you are not logged on to a client machine with that same username and password, then it should prompt for credential to authenticate for access to that ................. `\\<IPAddress>\<ShareName>`.

Comment: Agreed, try that.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT iam using different username to login in pc-2. but when iam accessing it still not asking credential. is it because in pc-2 already have my main user setting ? or i haven't set the NTFS permissions because i can't find it

Comment: From a command prompt, run `net use /del *` and then try accessing the share via UNC and tell me what happens afterward. This should remove any saved cached credentials on the machine in case that's the problem. Otherwise, check the advanced sharing and verify that you have the option checked to `Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers` or `Turn on password protected sharing` https://i.imgur.com/4B56MaB.png